# Dependencies on another module variable? Getting Error "is a list of string, known only after apply │"

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am getting error on "This value does not have any attributes.". How do I setup dependencies that module vpc must runs prior?

From the main file I call the following modules

```
module "vpc" {
  source      = "../../modules/vpc"
  environment = "demo"

}

module "eks-cluster" {
  source      = "../../modules/eks-cluster"
  environment = "demo"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.my_vpc_id
  my_public_subnets = module.vpc.my_public_subnets_id
}
```

main.tf within ../../modules/eks-cluster

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "research-cluster" {
  name     = var.my_cluster_name
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.research-cluster.arn

  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.research-cluster.id]
    subnet_ids         = var.my_public_subnets.id
  }
```

Error I am getting

```
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on ../../modules/eks-cluster/main.tf line 79, in resource "aws_eks_cluster" "demo-cluster":
│   79:     subnet_ids         = var.my_public_subnets.id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.my_public_subnets is a list of string, known only after apply
│
│ This value does not have any attributes.
```

Comment: How did you define `my_public_subnets_id` and `my_public_subnets`?

Comment: The code provided doesn't match your error? Could you try creating an [mcve] that is runnable to reproduce the exact error please?

Answer (score 0):

In general, terraform is able to handle dependencies properly in 99% of all cases, but you can still set artificial dependencies by using the [depends_on meta-argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/depends_on.html) - for this to work your terraform version should be => 0.13.

By using your code snippet, it would be something like:

```
module "eks-cluster" {
  depends_on = [module.vpc]
  source      = "../../modules/eks-cluster"
  environment = "demo"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.my_vpc_id
  my_public_subnets = module.vpc.my_public_subnets_id
}
```

However, by the looks of it, it very well may be the way your outputs are set up in the vpc module, or the way your variables are set in the eks-cluster module.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "However, by the looks of it, it very well may be the way your outputs are set up"?